# Compiling with unused and unavailable classes (like StageText on web)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a common codebase which I am using to export for mobile (iOS+Android) desktop (OSX+Windows) and web (SWF)

99% of the code is compatible everywhere, and it just works

However, there are a couple instances (like StageText), where it won't work. In those cases, I want to use a different class (like TextField or TLFTextField). Logically, this is fine... however it won't compile

I have something like-

```
var myStageText:StageText;
var myRegularText:TextField;

if(isAIR) {
myStageText = new StageText();
} else {
myRegularText = new TextField();
}
```

How can I let this compile everywhere, without turning off error checking?

Answer (score 0):

Ah okay, I realized I can do it by using wildcard object definitions and setting the class by name... something like:

```
var textInput:*;
var customClass:Class;

if(isAIR) {
customClass = getDefinitionByName("flash.text.StageText") as Class;
textInput = new customClass();
textInput.stage = stage;
} else {
textInput = new TextField();
addChild(textInput
}
```